# OpenGL VAO always drawing first Vertex from origin

Tags: opengl, d, vao

The title sums up my issue, but no matter what I set the first vertex as, OpenGL always draws it at the origin. I've tried this on a school computer and it wasn't a problem but I'm not at school and it's possible something I've changed is causing the issue. Regardless, I see no reason why this should happen. In case syntax seems weird, this code is written in D but should be an almost seamless port from C.

My code is:

```
class Mesh
{
this(vec3[] vertices, uint[] indices)
{    
    draw_count = indices.length;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);

    glGenBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, vertex_array_buffers.ptr);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_array_buffers[POSITION_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.length * vertices.sizeof, vertices.ptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(cast(GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, cast(void*)0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_array_buffers[INDEX_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.length * indices.sizeof, indices.ptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
void draw()
{
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, draw_count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, cast(const(void)*)0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
private:
    enum 
    {
        POSITION_VB,
        INDEX_VB,
        NORMAL_VB,
        NUM_BUFFERS
    };
GLuint vertex_array_object;
GLuint vertex_array_buffers[NUM_BUFFERS];
vec3 normals;
int draw_count;
}
```

Comment: and the `vertices[indices[0]]` is not 0 (or any of hem)?

Comment: My vertices are defined as `auto vertices = [vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f), vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f)];`

Comment: and you only have indices from 0 to 2 (inclusive)?

Comment: In this example yes however I've also used this code in a very basic OBJ loader and the test cube model I'm using also have vertices pinned to the origin.

Comment: I've run the app on Ubuntu at school and it renders the triangle fine. However on Elementary OS it does not render the triangle correctly still.